# Efficiently matching Words against a sorted Vocabulary in Python

Tags: python, search

On one hand, I have an alphabetically sorted noun vocabulary (#7000)

```
aardvark
abacus
abbey
abbreviation
abdomen
ability
abnormal
```

On the other hand I have a set of words (#1E6)

```
['Hello', 'airport', 'really', 'sorry', 'to', 'hear', 'this'...]
```

What is the most efficient way to find out if a word is present in the vocabulary, and the index?

I could simply use lists/arrays and compare strings, but this does not take advantage of the alphabetic sorting of the vocabulary

Comment: Quick searching in a sorted array/list -> binary search, with log(n) complexity

Comment: You could use sets, or dictionaries, or [binary search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists).

Comment: You can load the vocabulary as dictionary. The value can be the index. Since the lookup time of a dictionary is O(1), I think it can be quite beneficial. I mean still, loading from the file will take some time, but it will take time anyway you do it.

Comment: @MensurQulami Works for me as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As commented previously:

```
>>> vocab = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> vocab_lookup = {k:v for v,k in enumerate(vocab)}
```

And now all you need to use is `dict.get` or simply `dict[]`

```
>>> 'a' in vocab_lookup
True
>>> 'd' in vocab_lookup
False
>>> vocab_lookup.get('a')
0
>>> vocab_lookup.get('d')
>>> # None
```

Comment: No need to create a dictionary. You might as well use a `set`.

Comment: Since when sets have indexes?

Comment: Correct, forgot about the index! My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html#searching-sorted-lists) in order to take advantage of the sorted vocabulary:

```py
In [1]: d = ["aardvark", "abacus", "abbey", "abbreviation"]
In [2]: w = ['Hello', 'airport', 'really', 'sorry', 'to', 'hear', 'this', "aardvark"]
In [3]: for wd in w:
    ...:     try:
    ...:         index = bisect.bisect_left(d, wd)
    ...:         found = d[index]
    ...:         if found == wd:
    ...:             print(f"{wd} found at index {index}")
    ...:     except IndexError:
    ...:         pass
    ...:
aardvark found at index 0
```

Another option would be to use a dictionary, and search for `word in set` or `dictionary.get(word)` for the index - You can read my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56097997/how-does-python-implement-dictionaries/56098068#56098068) for details about `dict` implementation in CPython.

Comment: Good and efficient solution, I will acccept if nothing better comes by

Comment: Actually the dictionnary is simpler

Comment: You can use either. You should run some tests on your actual data to see which one is faster, or just pick the one you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

If the dictionary has unique entries (as I would expect), you can use a dict. `x in dict` returns `true` if `x` is a key in the given `dict` and (given no hash collisions) takes static time so that is the best we could ever get. It's worth mentioning that the worst case is `O(n)` but it is usually close to the best case. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4857919/why-does-dict-have-worst-case-on-for-so-many-operations) question for details.

To get the dict with the indices as values, use this line:

```
newdict = dict((k, v) for k, v in enumerate(sortedlist))
```

[Edit:] Note that this does not rely on a sorted list or any list at all. It will work for any iterable including open files with one word per line or the string.split() ...

If you want to keep your current data structure, you can use subtyping or docoration to keep a dict under the hood that is updated along and is used for this kind of lookup.